# multiple approval process and required to enter all of them

Tags: approval-process

my scenario is that i need 2 approval manager to approve my record based on different criteria/reasons. i created 2 approval process

Order:1 - approval process entry criteria: - reason 1 check box = true

Order:2 - approval process entry criteria: - reason 2 check box = true

my intentions is that i would like my record to enter both these approval process simultaneously so when approval manager from process 2 approved for reason 2 then we know that now is pending approval manager from process 1 to approve the record for reason 1. if either 1 rejected, the whole record will be rejected.

Or, after approval manager from approval process approved for reason 1 then i would like the record to proceed to approval process 2. From what i tested, if it fulfill approval process 1 criteria then it would not proceed to next approval process. is that so?

Thanks.